# Widget buildRow not appearing

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am working on one of the screens of my app, my first widget buildrow shows up perfectly however the second one does not appear, is this because my screen is not wide enough? I do have 3 buttons within the first buildrow, does that mean it will not show up because it is below it? Here is my code! Please let me know if anyone can help!

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.task.name),
      ),
      body: Material(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: timerText,
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 0,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: disable
                          ? null
                          : () {
                        setState(() {
                          StudyViewModel.stopwatch.reset();
                        });
                      },
                      color: Colors.red,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 60.0,
                        vertical: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Reset",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (StudyViewModel.stopwatch.isRunning) {
                            StudyViewModel.stopwatch.stop();
                            disable = false;
                          } else {
                            StudyViewModel.stopwatch.start();
                            disable = true;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      color: Colors.green,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 60.0,
                        vertical: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Play/Pause",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: disable
                          ? null
                          : () async {
                        widget.task.elapsedTime =
                            StudyViewModel.milliToElapsedString(
                                StudyViewModel
                                    .stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds);
                        await StudyViewModel.saveFile();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      color: Colors.yellow,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 60.0,
                        vertical: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Save",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildRow(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(StudyViewModel.studies[index].name,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: false,
          itemCount: StudyViewModel.studies[index].tasks.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int taskIndex) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(StudyViewModel.studies[index].tasks[taskIndex].name),
              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32.0),
              subtitle: Text(
                  StudyViewModel.studies[index].tasks[taskIndex].elapsedTime),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to `wrap` your middle `RaisedButton` with `Flexible`.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.task.name),
    ),
    body: Material(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: timerText,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: disable
                        ? null
                        : () {
                            setState(() {
                              StudyViewModel.stopwatch.reset();
                            });
                          },
                    color: Colors.red,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 60.0,
                      vertical: 20.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Reset",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          if (StudyViewModel.stopwatch.isRunning) {
                            StudyViewModel.stopwatch.stop();
                            disable = false;
                          } else {
                            StudyViewModel.stopwatch.start();
                            disable = true;
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      color: Colors.green,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 60.0,
                        vertical: 20.0,
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "Play/Pause",
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: disable
                        ? null
                        : () async {
                            widget.task.elapsedTime =
                                StudyViewModel.milliToElapsedString(
                                    StudyViewModel
                                        .stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds);
                            await StudyViewModel.saveFile();
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 60.0,
                      vertical: 20.0,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Save",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I was more asking about the second buildrow, that one does not show up when I run it on my emulator, do you have any advice for that?

Comment: Attach a screenshot so that we can understand.